# Is it possible to filter out on-premises mailboxes which are not migrated to cloud in GetUsers() graph api call

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

we are migrating around 10k mailboxes(mail accounts) from on-prem to cloud. During migration, is there any way to filter out the non-migrated mailboxes in GetUsers() graph api call, so that we can run backup only for the migrated mailboxes.
Is there any property of User object on basis of which we can filter the on-premise mailboxes? Or any other way?
We are using v1 version of microsoft graph api.

Comment: By mail boxes you mean the mail accounts? There are some onPrem custom attributes that can be added to the user. But they are only available in beta version of the Graph API. please check

Comment: yes by mail boxes I meant mail account. We are using v1 version of microsoft graph api.